# How to use FTP link/URL with FileZilla?

Tags: ftp, url, filezilla

I use FileZilla for FTP upload and download from FTP shares, websites. But I always struggle with using direct FTP links/URLs, like:

ftp://ftp.funet.fi/pub/standards/RFC/rfc959.txt

or FTP structured like this:

ftp://user:password@host:port/path

Is there a way to use FileZilla without setting up New Site for each FTP link? Can I just copy & paste the link to something in FileZilla that will start downloading, like any browser does?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can paste a URL to *Host* box on *Quickconnect bar*. Once you click *Quickconnect* button, the URL is parsed into *Host*, *Username*, *Password* and *Port*.

[image]

[image]

And actually even a protocol is recognized, so you can e.g. paste `sftp://` URL to connect with SFTP, what is otherwise not directly possible with *Quickconnect bar*.

Answer (score 1):

In **'View'** menu make sure that **'Qickconnect bar'** is enabled.
If so, toolbar with fields **'Host'**, **'Username'**, **'Password'**, **'Port'** and the button **'Qickconnect'** will be shown just under main menu.
Fill all needed fields, press **'Qickconnect'** and you'll got what you want.
Good luck!

Comment: I know about Quickconnect bar, but this is not what I'm asking here. I'm looking for a way to download directly with a link, without setting up details of Host, Port.. and other stuff.

Comment: @MikeTorrettinni, in this case, why don't just use any browser? Almost all today browsers can download file by direct ftp link. It's easiest way, as for me. Using Filzilla only makes sense if you need access to directories or other extended features.

Comment: I guess this is not possible with FileZilla, I was hoping I could use it for all my ftp stuff, too bad I can't.